# Reset a variable to 0 in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been looking around for a while now for an answer to this.

Here's my code:

```
function appendShopItem(shopItem, subTotal)
{
    // Create the list item:
    var item = document.createElement( 'li' );

    // Set its contents:
    item.appendChild( document.createTextNode( 
        shopItem.name + ' - ' + shopItem.cost + ' Gold'
    ) );

    // Add it to the list:
    list.appendChild( item );

    var radio = document.createElement( 'button' );
    var text = document.createTextNode( "Buy " + shopItem.name + " for " + shopItem.cost + " Gold");
    radio.name = 'shop';
    radio.value = shopItem.name;
    radio.onclick = function () {
        subTotal += shopItem.cost;
        addValue( shopItem, subTotal );
    };

    radio.appendChild( text );
    document.body.appendChild( radio );

    var lineBreak= document.createElement("BR");
    document.body.appendChild(lineBreak);
}

function addValue(shopItem, subTotal)
{
    document.getElementById("extraSubHeader").innerHTML = "Current Total: " + subTotal + " Gold"
}

function enterShop(position, locationNames, locationDescriptions, buttons, buttonActions, shopItems, shopCosts)
{
    subTotal = 0;

    document.getElementById("extraHeader").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("extraHeader").innerHTML = "Welcome to the Shop!";

    document.getElementById("extraSubHeader").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("extraSubHeader").innerHTML = "Current Total: 0 Gold"

    document.getElementById("list").style.visibility = "visible";


    document.getElementById("option1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("option2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("optionalInfo").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("subHeader").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("actionButton").innerHTML = "Leave Shop";
    document.getElementById("actionButton").onclick = function (){ loadData(position, locationNames, locationDescriptions, buttons, buttonActions, shopItems, shopCosts); hideShop(); }
    document.getElementById("header").style.visibility = "hidden";

    for( var i = 0;  i < shopItems.length;  ++i )
    {
        appendShopItem( shopItems[i], subTotal );
    }

    var clearButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var text = document.createTextNode("Clear Selection");
    clearButton.onclick = function () {
        subTotal = 0;
    };
    clearButton.appendChild(text);
    document.body.appendChild(clearButton);
}
```

The variable `subTotal` increases depending on what price the item you select is. If I click the button multiple times, `subTotal` increases. This works fine, but there is also a button to **reset** the total. This is where the problem is; even if I set subTotal to 0, it still continues to increment from where it last left off.

For example, if the price of the item was `10`, clicking the button `5` times would make `subTotal` into `50`. If I then click `Clear Selection` (the "reset" button), `subTotal` should go back to being `0`. However, clicking the button again would make `subTotal` into `60`, instead of defaulting to `0` and then becoming `10`.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please post minimum relevant code, and perhaps recreate your problem in a fiddle

Comment: This looks like a problem on the presentation rather than with wrong value of the variable.

Comment: 1. post the html 2. when do you call enterShop? 3. have you considered using angular? jquery is one of the worst ways to create a set of HTML elements that represent data because it's very verbose and has no simple way to update the elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a classic variable scoping issue because of Closure.

In `appendShopItem` you have this event handler

```
radio.onclick = function () {
    subTotal += shopItem.cost;
    addValue( shopItem, subTotal );
};
```

And the subTotal that is bound to eventHandler is whatever was passed when the `appendShopItem` was called.

So even when you reset `subTotal` to `0`, an earlier value is still bound to it, and as soon as radio button is clicked, the old value of `subTotal` is used.

You can refactor so that `subTotal` is not passed around, but make it a variable accessible for all these functions.

Comment: This works brilliantly. I simply defined `subTotal` earlier on in the script and didn't pass it to the function, it works now.